# Overlay background images in the same div tag

Tags: css, image, html, background

Is there a way to overlay/overlap two or more images using one div only? I wanted something like this in my css:

```
#nice_container {
    background: url('nice_background.jpg') repeat-y z(0);
    background: url('nice_logo.jpg') top left no-repeat z(1);
}
```

Where z(#) would be the z-index, then I would just use a nice `<div id="nice_container">...</div>`

### EDIT

Thanks for the quick answers! [Here's the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10115887/1326147).

Comment: Please consider moving your edit/solution down into a solution.

Comment: Thanks @Barett, I did reply to my own question before, but at that time I thought it was not appropriate. Since I got so many answers I ended up removing it... I undeleted it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with css3 you can use multiple background in css

http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

but not every browser can handle it !
Firefox has supported multiple backgrounds since version 3.6 (Gecko 1.9.2), Safari since version 1.3, Chrome since version 10, Opera since version 10.50 (Presto 2.5) and Internet Explorer since version 9.0.

Examples :

```
#exampleA {
width: 500px;
height: 250px;
background-image: url(decoration.png), url(ribbon.png), url(old_paper.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left top, right bottom, left top;
}
```

or:

```
#exampleA {
width: 500px;
height: 250px;
background: url(decoration.png) left top no-repeat, url(ribbon.png) right bottom no-   repeat, url(old_paper.jpg) left top no-repeat;
}
```

I suppose that the order you define the background images is the order of the stack

Comment: Thank you! Your second example is actually the closest thing to my request... But I still didn't manage to get it working, and I'm using the latest Firefox...

Comment: happy to help you, please indicate the answer you prefer by clicking the "accept" tick at the left of the question to indicate that it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **CSS3** multiply background write like this:

```
background: url('nice_background.jpg') repeat-y , background: url('nice_logo.jpg') top left no-repeat;
```

But it's not working in IE8 & below.

Check this http://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-css3-multiple-backgrounds/#fbid=Mg9Q6GSmvXB

Answer (score 1):

Only css3 supports multiple backgrounds - so depends on browser support you require

http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

Firefox has supported multiple backgrounds since version 3.6 (Gecko 1.9.2), Safari since version 1.3, Chrome since version 10, Opera since version 10.50 (Presto 2.5) and Internet Explorer since version 9.0.

Answer (score 1):

So thank you everyone for the quick answers! It works like this:

```
 #nice_container {
     background: url('nice_logo.jpg') top left no-repeat,
                 url('nice_background.jpg') repeat-y
 }
```

Notice that you have to write the smaller or transparent background images first (the final background stays at the end of the line).
Thank you for helping in reaching the solution!

Answer (score 0):

this may show the way

```
div.test {
    background-image: url(../pix/logo_quirksmode.gif), url(../pix/logo_quirksmode_inverted.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: top left, top right;
    width: 385px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overlay two images, and you want it to work in every browser, you can do something like this (but it's no longer a div):

```
<img src="img1.png" style="background-image: url(img2.png)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 allows us to specify multiple background images in a single div, using nothing more than a simple comma-separated list.

```
#example1 {
width: 500px;
height: 250px;
background-image: url(sheep.png), url(betweengrassandsky.png);
background-position: center bottom, left top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

**for more details you can read here about:** **[Multiple Backgrounds with CSS3](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/)**